# How to solve a duplicate class error in Appium?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I need to do some Android testing, so using Appim java-client 7.0 version along with selenium files, By using both jar files in the same project i was facing the duplicate class error due to org.openqa.selenium package which is present in both jars

Comment: Hi! Can we get a little more info on the issue? Is this error showing up on your idea or at compile time?

Comment: During the compile time.

Answer (score -1):

Your project setup is not correct, you should have only [appium-java-client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0) in your project [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Appium already has Selenium as the dependency, and the tricky thing is that it relies on a **specific** Selenium version and in case of mismatch you will suffer from a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)

[image]

So consider using a build/dependency management system like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org) and make sure to define only Appium Java Client dependency for your project (maybe you might also want to add [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/) or [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/)), all other Appium dependencies will be resolved automatically via [Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) mechanism

Check out [Code Examples - Appium with Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) for comprehensive explanation and sample projects.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, there is a known bug for the issue i am facing, open source project Appium Java-client https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/1021.